# xcodebuild: why build dir differs for target and scheme

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

How to access the result binary of xcode project.
I have to track what kind of build is used -target or -scheme!?

when run

> $ xcodebuild -project ~/proj/proj_path.xcodeproj -scheme myscheme

build dir is located in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/...

but when i run

> $ xcodebuild -project ~/proj/proj_path.xcodeproj -target mytarget

build dir is located in ~/proj/build/
BUT when i run

> $ xcodebuild -project ~/proj/proj_path.xcodeproj -target mytarget
> -showBuildSettings -json

"BUILD_DIR" : "/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/..." NOT in ~/proj/build/

Is it normal or I do not understand why for target it uses build folder inside project directory.
And how to properly build? using target or scheme? Because I have identical lists for targets and schemes.